# How do I export output to csv?

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export the output of the list of combinations, but I can't seem to get it right? Can someone help please?

I tried with that and numpy and whatever solution I could find

```
import csv
from itertools import combinations

comb = combinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59], 6) 

for i in list(comb): 
    print(i)

writer = csv.writer(data.csv)
writer.writerow([i])
```

Expected result would be output in a csv but the csv is never created and it only shows me the output in the terminal.

Comment: Did you close the writer?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't write the same output you print? Open the writer before the loop; print and write `i` to your output destinations.

Comment: There are multiple issues I see with this code.  This code simply won't work, and shouldn't even run as it has at least one syntax error that I can see.  1) what is **data.csv**?  Is that the file name you want to output to?  If so, it needs to be in quotes.  2) You iterate over **comb** using 'i', but then you also use 'i' outside of that loop.  That doesn't look right.  3) For the line **writer.writerow([i])**, do you mean to be creating a new list?

Comment: Yes @tripleee, I realized that after I hit <Return> and fixed it. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect that you want something like this:

```
import csv
from itertools import combinations

comb = combinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59], 6) 

with open("/tmp/data.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for i in comb:
        writer.writerow(i)
```

Note that this writes a 800MB file.

A nice thing you could do for readability of your code would be to use **range()** to define your data.  This would make it easy to play with the size of your dataset.  Like this:

```
comb = combinations(range(1,60), 6)
```

@triplee added some good comments to his answer that apply equally here, since they speak to your original code.  We're guessing you wanted **data.csv** to be a literal file name, not an attribute **csv** of an undefined object named **data**. Either way though, you have to first open a file so you have a file-like object, and then pass that to **csv.writer()**; For efficiency, there's no reason to expand the entire list of combinations into memory (which is what the list() call would do) and instead let the combinations() method generate our data piecemeal while we loop.

Comment: ... You beat me, maybe you want to copy some commentary from my answer before I delete it?

Comment: Yes, your comments are great.  I started to provide similar comments, but there were so many problems with the code, that I gave up and decided that the new code could speak for itself.  For example, even if he put quotes around "data.csv", csv.writer takes a file handle, not a file name.  You can do whatever you think is best.  And explaining the list() thing seemed like maybe too much for the OP.  You can edit my answer if you want to.

Comment: I'll add your comments to my answer.

Comment: Wow, thank you guys for your help and advice ! You're totally right about the readability and the data.csv  I'm still learning so, both comments are super helpful in my comprehension !